# Excel Macro saving file to the wrong directory

Tags: excel, vba

I have looked at quite a lot of similar questions, but none of them seem to work for my specific issue.

I have a macro that saves my file with a new name if it encounters a file with the same name.

What keeps happening is that it saves the original file to the correct folder, but then when it encounters the file name the next time I save it, the instanced file gets saved to the same folder as the template rather than the folder that they should go to.

In the example below, my template file is saved in the "M:\Excel\" directory.

It saves the first "TEST" file into the "M:\Excel\SavedVersions\" directory since the file name doesn't exist yet.

Then when I run the macro again to have it automatically save an instanced version (ie - "TESTrev1"), it keeps saving the instanced versions to the "M:\Excel\" directory instead of saving it to the "SavedVersions" subfolder.

Not sure what needs to be changed or done differently to get the instanced versions to save to the correct folder.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance! :)

```
Sub TEST()

    ActiveWorkbook.Save
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        GetNextAvailableName("M:\Excel\SavedVersions\TEST.xlsm")

End Sub

Function GetNextAvailableName(ByVal strPath As String) As String

    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

        Dim strFolder As String, strBaseName As String, strExt As String, i As Long
        strFolder = .GetParentFolderName("M:\Excel\SavedVersions\")
        strBaseName = .GetBaseName("TEST")
        strExt = .GetExtensionName(".xlsm")

        Do While .FileExists(strPath)
            i = i + 1
            strPath = .BuildPath(strFolder, strBaseName & "rev" & i & "." & strExt)
        Loop

    End With

    GetNextAvailableName = strPath

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code was unnecessarily complex.

**Try this simpler version.**

```
Sub TEST()

    ActiveWorkbook.Save
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:= _
        GetNextAvailableName("M:\Excel\SavedVersions\TEST.xlsm")

End Sub

Function GetNextAvailableName(ByVal strPath As String) As String

        Dim i as Interger: i = 0

        Do Until Len(Dir(strPath)) = 0
            i = i + 1
            strPath = "M:\Excel\SavedVersions\TESTrev" & i & ".xlsm"
        Loop

    GetNextAvailableName = strPath

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Keep your code simple. If your path is constant then might as well define a variable for it so that it can be used whenever and whereever you want. This way if there is any change in the path, you have to make the change at only one place.
2. While saving the file, also specify the `FileFormat` parameter to avoid problems. You might want to read more about it [HERE](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s5/win001.htm)

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Const sPath As String = "M:\Excel\SavedVersions\"

Sub Sample()
    Dim flName As String

    flName = sPath & GetNextAvailableName()

    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=flName, _
                          FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
End Sub

Function GetNextAvailableName() As String
    Dim i As Integer: i = 1
    Dim newFile As String

    newFile = "TestRev" & i & ".xlsm"

    Do Until Dir(sPath & newFile) = ""
        i = i + 1
        newFile = "TestRev" & i & ".xlsm"
    Loop

    GetNextAvailableName = newFile
End Function
```